# Append two Integers, each representing a nibble, to a hexadec. number

Tags: java, jpeg

I write the bitstream for a JPEG Encoder, I'm facing this problem:

I built Pairs for the AC Cosinus Coefficients (after Quantization) in an int[]array. Each Pair: (Number of Zeros/ Category of the Coefficient after JPEG standard). **Out of these two integers, I have to form one hexadecimal number**, where as one integer of the pair representing one nibble. The hexadecimal Numbers have to be huffman-encoded later.
Example: My Pair is (4,5), i need it as (0x45).

How can I do that? My way is to convert the Integers to a String, append the Strings, and get them back as one Integer. However, the compiler says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0fffffff5"

```
//Get a Pair (Numbers of Zeros, Coefficient)
            int[]singlePair_ref = acPairs_ref.get(i);

            //Convert to Wrapper Class Integer
            Integer firstNibble_ref = ((Integer)singlePair_ref[0]);
            Integer secondNibble_ref = ((Integer)singlePair_ref[1]);

            //Convert to String
            String firstNibbleString_ref = firstNibble_ref.toHexString(singlePair_ref[0]);
            String secondNibbleString_ref = secondNibble_ref.toHexString(singlePair_ref[1]);

            //Append Strings
            String byteValueString_ref = firstNibbleString_ref+secondNibbleString_ref;
            Integer byteValue_ref = 0;

            //Convert the new formed "one" (formed out of two) Number back to Integer
            byteValue_ref.parseInt(byteValueString_ref); //Line throws Exception
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks a lot!
Daniel

Edit:
if I do it like this

```
YACforHuffman_ref[i] = (singlePair_ref[0] << 4) | singlePair_ref[1];
```

the out put is decimal (3,6) becomes 54. If I convert the result of this equation with

```
String YACforHuffman_ref = Integer. Integer.toHexString((singlePair_ref[0] << 4) |    singlePair_ref[1];
```

like Mike did above, I get trouble for a value bigger than 9 (Value A-F), now I know what you meant @Mike, sorry I didnt get it at first. How can I solve this?

Comment: It would be great if somebody can solve this, but I feel this is a really slow way, to append the Integers over String. If anybody has a simple, fast implementation (maybe a class or a method) for this problem, it was even better. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using |. You should be using +

Comment: this is the version of Ferda, see below

Comment: dont get me wrong, both versions work, whats not working is the "toHexString" Method, as you assumed, it doesnt work with values that are represented by Letters, > 9

Comment: Ah yes. Because A-F is not an int, right ?

Comment: yes, it throws a NumberFormatException, because he wants int values, no letters

Comment: If he was passing in a letter then it's already a string though.. In which case you don't have to do toHexString because it's already a hex string

Comment: yes, but I need it as an Integer or an int, and neither take letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure how you would pass in values over 9 into your integer pair but assuming you can pass in 0-15 then you could potentially do something such as this:

```
public class Hex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNum  = 4;
        int secondNum = 15;

        System.out.println( Integer.toHexString( firstNum * 16 + secondNum ) );
        // Or if you find it easier to understand
        // System.out.println( Integer.toHexString( ( firstNum << 4 ) + secondNum ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: i can pass values till 15, each value is 4 bits, so 15 is the maximum. Your algorithm would convert my example pair (4,5) to a decimal 69, I need it as 0x45 tho, but thanks anyway. Tell me if Im wrong.

Comment: Test it. It will convert it to 45

Comment: oh, because of the toHexString, right? Im sorry, I should have tested before judging.

Comment: yes it works, I just have one more question. In the case of, for example pair (0,1) or (0,13) to 0x1 or 0xD, instead of 0x01 or 0x0D. The question is, is 0x1 and 0x01 the same? Thank you very much so far!

Comment: Yes they're 0x1 and 0x01 are the same in the same way that 1 and 01 are the same in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Mike's right. If you want to use the result as a number and not as a string you need just a numeric expression. Adapted to your code sample:

```
int[] singlePair_ref = acPairs_ref.get(i);
int byteValue_ref = (singlePair_ref[0] << 4) | singlePair_ref[1];
```

Providing the higher nibble comes first. You can also cast the result to byte.

--- Ferda